# Converting a complex dictionary list to a dictionary

Tags: python, django

I would like to convert this dictionary list below into a dictionary

```
data=[
    {
        'code':'matata',
        'commandes':[
            {
                'date':'12-10-22',
                'content':[
                    {
                        'article':'Article1',
                        'designation':'Designe1',
                        'quantity':5
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I would like to have this result, just the starting brackets that we change to {..}

```
data={
{
    'code':'matata',
    'commandes':[
        {
            'date':'12-10-22',
            'content':[
                {
                    'article':'Article1',
                    'designation':'Designe1',
                    'quantity':5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. Dictionaries contain `Key Value` pairs. So you must also have a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather, You can use the 0th index of list and return dictionary.

```
data = data[0]
print(data)

#output
data ={
    'code':'matata',
    'commandes':[
        {
            'date':'12-10-22',
            'content':[
                {
                    'article':'Article1',
                    'designation':'Designe1',
                    'quantity':5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
```

## (UPDATE 1)If you have multiple proucts:

```
for product in data:
   print(product)
```

## (UPDATE 2) To print comma:

```
for product in data:
   print(product, end =",")
```

Comment: And for example if I had 2 or more product dictionaries on the list

Comment: #Use for loop for this

for product in data:
         print(product)

Comment: how i will implement the for loop here

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't write code in comment section. So I will write code for for loop in above code section and UPDATE.  Check there. OK !

Comment: Look at the updated code just below my previous code. !!!

Comment: I would like to add a comma (,) to each dictionary iteration
How to do it at print level

Comment: Check above answer in #UPDATE -2